# Set pixel grid properly in Photoshop cc 2017

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pixels

How can I set pixel grid in Photoshop cc 2017 to display 1 by 1 pixel grid?

Here are my grid view and its settings:

[image][image]

After disabling an ordinary grid and enabling the pixel grid I got another problem. The color of the grid is the same as the background or the grid just not showing. Here is the pixel grid view and settings for the grid:

[image][image]

Comment: This is really strange. Try to turn off this grid and turn on Pixel Grid (View - Show - Pixel Grid).

Comment: @IvanKuckir, thanks. It worked out. Should I delete my question or will you answer it?

Answer (score 1):

This is really strange. Try to report this as a bug to Adobe.

Since you need a pixel-wide grid, try to turn off the standard grid and turn on a Pixel Grid (View - Show - Pixel Grid).

I think you can not change the color of the pixel grid, so if it is the same as the background, try to hide your background temporarily.

Comment: Wait. Got one more problem. Will refresh the question.